# How to format a Datetime on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a query as list and return a DateTime,but what I want is return a DateTime.ToShortDateString(), and not the whole date with time.

My Model :

```
.......
public DateTime? DatePost { get; set; }
```

And the query is :

```
 Select(x => new {
                  x.Price,
                  x.CityFrom,
                  x.CityTo,
                  x.ItemsCount,
                  x.DatePost,
...........
```

Answer (score -1):

The `Select` is a *projection* mechanism of a list one object type to another.

One can simply change the `Select` to *project* it into an object more appealing to your situation.

A simple modification to your example such as this satisfies your requirement. (using C# 6/7 found in Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 respectively),

```
Select(x => new {
                  x.Price,
                  x.CityFrom,
                  x.CityTo,
                  x.ItemsCount,
                  DatePost = x.DatePost?.ToShortDateString() ?? "unknown",
```

We are handling the null situation of what is in the db by using the null coalescing operator (`??`) which says in that situation return the string "unknown".

Comment: I got a error, "Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment,simple member or access".

Comment: @NathielPaulino which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I check something, and the C# still is the 5.0, I will try to install the new one